# Change HTTP response code in CXF SOAP Fault

Tags: soap, exception, cxf

I have this error

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <soap:Fault>
      <faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
      <faultstring>Message part {http://soap.ws.server.wst.fit.cvut.cz/}createOrders was not recognized.  (Does it exist in service WSDL?)</faultstring>
    </soap:Fault>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

which is completely fine. But the problem is that CXF is returning Internal Server Error (HTTP 500). I would expect it to return 400 Bad Request because a wrong request is causing this. How can I change that?

**DETAILS**

The wrong request which produces the error above - there should be `<soap:createOrder/>` instead of `<soap:createOrders/>`.

```
POST http://localhost:8080/wst-server-1.0.0/services/soap/order

POST data:
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soap="http://soap.ws.server.wst.fit.cvut.cz/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <soap:createOrders/>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

[no cookies]

Request Headers:
Content-Length: 238
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Comment: Are you catching the soap fault? I'm assuming CXF is used in a client which you are writing (debugging) and the message you show was sent by the server to which it was making a request. I'm also assuming that your application is a web application and it responds to its clients with the 500 error.

Comment: @LeeMeador  I don't know where to catch it because this happens before a `@WebMethod` is called. It's something in the CXF...

Comment: Perhaps you can add some details about who is calling whom carefully identifying the server and the client and which one is returning the above message and which one is doing an error 500.

Comment: @LeeMeador I updated the question. If I send the wrong request I want to receive 400 instead of 500... CXF knows that it's a client fault (correct soap:Fault)...

Comment: The server (localhost) is returning a soap fault message but you didn't show the response header which would contain the return code. Can you add it above?

Comment: I found this by Googling for "CXF response code 500". It might help. [http://cxf.547215.n5.nabble.com/CXF-Fault-Response-Code-td566788.html](http://cxf.547215.n5.nabble.com/CXF-Fault-Response-Code-td566788.html)

Comment: @LeeMeador I don't understand. The response is HTTP 500 (Internal Server Error)... What else do you need to know?

Comment: Per SOAP spec, all soap faults are to be returned with 500 status code.  Not returning 500 for a soap fault will likely break other applications.

Comment: @DanielKulp Should I use a different approach or is it fine to return faultcode soap:Client with HTTP 500 when the request is bad?

Comment: The 500 return code with the soap:Client fault code is the correct behavior for this case.

Comment: @DanielKulp Thank you. I'll leave it as it is then...

Answer (score 1):

I know maybe this is too late for the answer but another way to handle HTTP status code is using CXF interceptors.

you can add an interceptor in your server CXF configure

```
 public class ServiceConfigurer implements CxfConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureServer(Server server) {
         server.getEndpoint().getOutFaultInterceptors().add(new ChangingStatusCodeInterceptor();
    }
 }
```

and in your interceptor, you can change this

```
public class SaveInfluxDataInterceptor extends WSS4JOutInterceptor {

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(SoapMessage soapMessage) {
        ((Fault)exchange.get(Exception.class)).setStatusCode(202); // this is because of soap12OutFaultInterceptor look to this fault
        // or you can use this
        // exchange.getOutFaultMessage().put(Message.RESPONSE_CODE, 202);
    }
}
```

I used Camel with CXF. maybe this solution should change in yours.